# gimp extract pencle drawing from photo

Tags: gimp

I struggle to get good results extracting pencel drawings from photos with gimp.

I try approches like:
Adding an alpha channle and selecting white and deleteing. But this is unrellable as there is some shadeing preventing clean result no matter how much I play wit the settings.
The reuslt is also very washed out. So I try to increase its boldness by for example adding a glow fliter but again results are not great.

Does anyone have a recomendation what a good workflow might be.
I only have the photos now so I dont have the option to recapture the images with a scanner to even out the white of the paper.

Comment: Maybe try [graphicdesign.se]?

Answer (score 0):

With modern Gimp (2.10) the best option to even out the background is:

- Decompose the image using `Filters ➤ Enhance ➤ Wavelet decompose`.
- Replace the `Residual` layer by its own average with `Filters ➤ Blur ➤ Pixelize` (and use the layer size as the block size)